# login with user roles in C# connected to MS Access database

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, authentication, oledbconnection

I'm reasonably new to c# and I want some advice in relation to my login form.

Currently when a user enters their username and password it is checked in the related MS Access database and then loads the form 'Splash_Screen'.

However, dependant on the access level assigned to the user i.e 'Admin' and 'General User' I would like it direct the user to a separate forms as I don't want 'General Users' to have the same functionality as 'Admin'.

I only have 2 types of access levels i.e 'Admin' or 'General_User'.

```
private void btn_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "select * from Account_Details where Email_Address = '"+txt_Username.Text+"' and Password = '" + txt_Password.Text + "'";

        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        int count = 0;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            count = count + 1;

        }
        if (count == 1)
        {
            this.Hide();
            Splash_Screen f2 = new Splash_Screen();
            f2.Show();

        }
        else if (count > 1)
        { 
            MessageBox.Show("Duplicate Username and Password");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username and Password is not correct");
        }

        connection.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question, so that now the entire snippet shows as code (indent by 4 spaces for this). I find it a little unclear where the problem is; are you looking for the right default column and table names in MS-Access, or is this a custom table you're using? Please [edit] that into your question. Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection; it is good practice to always use parameterized queries. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I have changed my initial question, hopefully it is slightly clearer. I just want the user to be taken to a separate form depending if they are an 'Admin user' or 'General user'. This is recorded in the database with the users details.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code to achieve the similar requirements. it worked for me. i hope it will help others who have this kind of requirements. i have created two textboxs named txtusername and txtpassword and one combobox for user roll and in OleDataAdapter i used a query to fetch data from users table where username and password are equal to whatever user types in textbox after that i used a if statement to check if there are any records in table than in a nested if i have checked that if comboboxroll is equal to admin than show adminform otherewise display userform.

```
 OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [users] Where [UserName]='" + txtUserName.Text + "' And [pwd]='" + txtPassword.Text + "' And [Roll]='" + cmbroll.Text + "'", conn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                if (cmbroll.Text == "Admin")
                {
                    MainFrm f = new MainFrm();
                    f.Show();
                    f.lblLogedUser.Text = txtUserName.Text;
                    this.Hide();
                }
                else {
                    MainFrmUser userform = new MainFrmUser();
                    userform.Show();
                    userform.lblLogedUser.Text = txtUserName.Text;
                    this.Hide();
                }
```